# Customize DataService namespace and EntityContainer

Tags: c#-4.0, ef-code-first, wcf-data-services

**Nutshell**: The Entity Framework Provider for WCF Data Services pulls the schema namespace and EntityContainer name directly from the namespace and class name of the DbContext, respectively.  This is also true for DbContexts that are developed using the code-first method.

Is there a way to modify this provider behavior *a posteriori*--that is, without modifying the class name or the EDM(X)?

**Background/caveats/opinion**: This is a handy behavior for prototyping, but in a production scenario, the class name is itself an implementation detail that should be hidden from service consumers.

Further, in my case the name cannot be changed, since I am using a framework that provides a very generic DbContext that I am then composing/extending.

Note that I am not discussing a way to create more "space" between the CLR and EDM representations of the data model.  Rather, I'm looking for a way to modify the behavior of the `DataService<T>` extension itself, so that the internal CLR namespace and DbContext extension class name (preserved in the EDM, *which is totally okay*) aren't exposed externally.

The specific customization points in the service metadata (custom-ns and custom-container below):

```
<edmx:Edmx Version="1.0" xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx">
    <edmx:DataServices m:DataServiceVersion="1.0" m:MaxDataServiceVersion="3.0" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
        <Schema Namespace="<custom-ns>" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/09/edm">
            <EntityType Name="EgEntity">
                .
                .
                .
            </EntityType>
            .
            .
            .
            <EntityContainer Name="<custom-container>" m:IsDefaultEntityContainer="true">
                <EntitySet Name="EgEntity" EntityType="<custom-ns>.EgEntity" />
                .
                .
                .
            </EntityContainer>
        </Schema>
    </edmx:DataServices>
</edmx:Edmx>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In code-first, you can specify the schema for tables in the SSDL with the [`Table`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.tableattribute.aspx) annotation (look at the [`Schema`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.tableattribute.schema.aspx) property).  Unfortunately, I don't think you can overwrite the schema namespaces used in the CSDL with either attributes or the model builder (please note that I haven't extensively researched this).

*You may attempt to play with [namespace aliases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htccxtad.aspx), although I'm not sure this would work as you intend.*

In model-first and database-first, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14561370/entity-framework-5-namespaces) which seems to answer yours.  Let me know if it doesn't.

I realize this answer is not too helpful, but I would like to suggest that you specify proper namespaces for your codebase, even (especially) for production.  This is because I can't immediately see why a namespace should be "hidden" in any normal scenario, but please do expand on your use-case if you disagree.

*That being said, I agree that one should be able to map proper CLR namespaces to different EDM schemas for other reasons, I guess everybody is OK with using the same names as long as they make sense.  By the way, don't forget vendor prefixes, especially since you're exposing these names to the network.*

Note that the third-party framework namespace shouldn't be relevant as long as the context class is not sealed.  Usually, entities are defined as POCOs so that's normally not a problem either.  Thus, the standard solution would be to extend this generic context class in a namespace of your own, along with the entities.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look.  Admittedly this wasn't too helpful.  It looks like you were thinking of "schemas" along the lines of the schema in the DB, and from there a mapping between differently-named CLR and EDM schemas.  However, I was writing about the namespace XML attribute of the DataService metadata "Schema" element, and how to generate a mapping between the EDM and the DataService.  I'll edit to give more specificity.

Comment: No yes, I mentioned both just in case; everything after the first sentence is about the CSDL (conceptual schema) exposed by the DS. The thing is, if you're using WCF with EF backend, the EDM generated from code conventions by EF is the same one that is used by DS (well, they're converted internally, but it's the same source). As such, you really have to generate the EDM you intend from EF (using code conventions and the model builder) and the DS will pick it up to generate its CSDL. That's why there's probably no option to map between the two; they're the same. Is subclassing really a problem?

Comment: Subclassing is pretty daunting in my case because of the dependency injection/repository pattern that I'm using, thus my casting about for a declarative solution.  I may be stuck, but I'll see if I can't come up with something.  Thanks for the clarification.